# Force variable to be local in SASS

Tags: variables, sass, local-variables

Consider, I have the following SASS partial:

```sass
@import '../modules/cdn';


$font-url: '#{$cdn-base-url}/fonts/MyFont';


@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src:
    url('#{$font-url}-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('#{$font-url}-regular.woff') format('woff')
  ;
}
```

I just want to save me some typing, so I define the `$font-url` helper variable. However, I don't want this variable to be global and to be exported to every file, which imports this one.

Right now, when I do:

```sass
@import 'partials/my-font';


p {
  font-family: MyFont, sans-serif;
  &:after {
    content: $font-url;
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following result:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src:
    url("https://cdn.example.com/fonts/MyFont-regular.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("https://cdn.example.com/fonts/My Font-regular.woff") format("woff")
  ;
}

p {
  font-family: MyFont, sans-serif;
}

p:after {
  content: "https://cdn.example.com/fonts/MyFont";
}
```

However, I would like compilation to fail at this case due to the missing `$font-url` variable (which shouldn't be exported).

Comment: Put that variable in `@font-face` scope? Could be a solution for you?

Comment: @ReSedano it could work, but I have multiple font-face definitions, so it wouldn't be practical.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found so far is to define a mixin to actually make the variable local:

```sass
@import '../../modules/cdn';


@mixin my-font {

  $font-url: '#{$cdn-base-url}/fonts/MyFont';

  @font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    src:
      url('#{$font-url}-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
      url('#{$font-url}-regular.woff') format('woff')
    ;
  }

}
```

And it should be called like this:

```sass
@import 'fonts/my-font';

@include my-font();
```